# Tab menu - jquery mouseover/mouseout problem

Tags: jquery

I am using the tab menu similar to http://yensdesign.com/tutorials/tabs/ but with hover instead of clicks. Currently i have to use 'default' to close the menus.

1. How can I start off with all the drop menu's closed?
2. When user hovers over the tabs the menu should expand and only close when user hovers out of the expanded menu.

Query used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".menu > li").mouseover(function(e){
  switch(e.target.id){
   case "default":
    //change status & style menu
    $("#default").addClass("active");
    $("#elec_gas").removeClass("active");
    $("#home_energy").removeClass("active");
    //display selected division, hide others
    $("div.default").css("display", "none");
    $("div.elec_gas").css("display", "none");
    $("div.home_energy").css("display", "none");
   break;
   case "elec_gas":
    //change status & style menu
    $("#default").removeClass("active");
    $("#elec_gas").addClass("active");
    $("#home_energy").removeClass("active");
    //display selected division, hide others
    $("div.default").css("display", "none");
    $("div.elec_gas").fadeIn();
    $("div.home_energy").css("display", "none");
   break;
   }
  //alert(e.target.id);
  return false;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with them closed, give the child menus a CSS of `display: none;` or do it in script, by adding this in your `document.ready` handler:

```
$("div.default, div.elec_gas, div.home_energy").hide();
```

---

For the hover-out of a cild closing them...use the [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event instead of [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/), like this:

```
$(".menu > li").mouseleave(function(e){
```

From [the `.mouseleave()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/):

> The `mouseleave` event differs from `mouseout` in the way it handles event bubbling. If `mouseout` were used in this example, then when the mouse pointer moved out of the Inner element, the handler would be triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The `mouseleave` event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the handler is triggered when the mouse leaves the **Outer** element, but not the **Inner** element.

Comment: @skanwal - Be sure to accept answers if they solve your problem via the checkmark beside the one that helped :)